# Why does the Thread.activeCount() method returns 2?

Tags: java

I am currently learning about Java threads.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
  }
}
```

Could anyone please tell me why does this method return the value 2? From what I understand, the only thread that is currently running is the "main" thread. I know that `Thread.activeCount()` "Returns an estimate of the number of active threads in the current thread's thread group and its subgroups", so is there a subgroup of this thread that has another active thread?

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Code could be running on a CPU with multiple cores or hyperthreading active. So really multiple threads can run at the same time

Comment: Make a thread dump and you can see what is active.

Comment: short answer: because two threads are estimated to be active. To get all *live* threads you can use [`Thread.getAllStackTraces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces()) - you will probably get more than 2 (Finalizer, Attach Listener, Reference Handler, Signal Dispatcher, ... probably more or less depending on system and other details)

Comment: What makes you think there should be only one thread? Java has threads for GC, AWT event despatch, RMI listeners, all kinds of things.

Comment: I thought that there should only be one thread since in the tutorial I am following it only shows 1 thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of guessing what threads these could be you can expand your code to write out the threads names:

```
public class ThreadCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Thread.activeCount() + " threads:");
        Thread[] allThreads = new Thread[10];
        Thread.enumerate(allThreads);
        for (Thread t: allThreads) {
            if (t != null) {
                System.out.format("%d %s%n", t.getId(), t.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my windows machine this outputs:

> ```
> 2 threads:
> 1 main
> 14 Monitor Ctrl-Break
> ```

So the second thread is a JVM-created thread that seems to exist to monitor the Ctrl-Break key combination. Whether this thread is started or not may depend on your environment (running from console versus running a GUI application, running on Windows versus running on Linux, on Mac, on ....)